# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having a problem about prepared statements
im trying to prevent a sql injection in my database so i tried to apply
prepared statements but i think im having a problem

this is the **collector_db.php**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$repassword = $_POST["repassword"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$mname = $_POST["mname"];

if($password == $repassword){
    global $dbConnection;
    $mysql_qry = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into  account_info(surname,firsname,middlename,username,pass,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);");
    $mysql_qry- >bind_param('ssssss','$surname,$fname,$mname,$username,$password,$email');

    $mysql_qry->execute();

    if ($connect->query($mysql_qry)=== TRUE){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Registration Success');";
        echo "window.close();";
        echo "</script>";
        $mysql_qry->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
    else{
        echo "REGISTRATION failed".$mysql_qry."<br>". $connect->error;
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Registration Failed');";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
elseif($password != $repassword){
    echo 'Password doesnt Match';
}
elseif($username == "" || $password == "" || $email == "" || $surname ==     "" || $fname == "" || $mname == "" || $repassword == ""){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Some of the Textfields is null');";
    echo "</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Error');";
    echo "</script>";
}

?>
```

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space between `$mysql_qry-` and `>` and execute query two time at `if ($connect->query($mysql_qry)=== TRUE){` and `$connect` is undefined in your code

Just execute it once

```
$mysql_qry = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into  account_info(surname,firsname,middlename,username,pass,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);");
$mysql_qry->bind_param('ssssss', $surname,$fname,$mname,$username,$password,$email);// remove quotes form here

if ($mysql_qry->execute()) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Registration Success');";
    echo "window.close();";
    echo "</script>";
    $mysql_qry->close();
}
```

Remove this part `if ($connect->query($mysql_qry)=== TRUE){...`

Comment: that fixed that error but can i ask some another question? Why am i not getting any data transferred in my database?

Comment: yaa sure you can ask!!

Comment: Check my updated answer remove quotes from bind_param . `$mysql_qry->bind_param('ssssss', $surname,$fname,$mname,$username,$password,$email);// remove quotes form here
`

Comment: Use `if (!$mysql_qry->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $mysql_qry->errno . ") " . $mysql_qry->error;
}` to check error